# Sincronizar un segundo audio cuando el primero termine y comience a sonar de nuevo con HTML5 y Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo una práctica en la que tengo dos pistas de audio (en loop) que las lanzo con clicks del mouse. Seguramente se pueda hacer más facilmente, pero soy un novatillo y estoy trasteando.

Lo que no logro es sincronizar los audios, es decir, si uno está sonando y se hace click en el otro, que comience a sonar cuando el otro comience el siguiente loop. Esto sería que una vez lanzado un audio, **si otro se activa se lance cuando el otro termine y comience a sonar de nuevo (loop)**.

Dejo el último código que hice rápidamente intentándolo con `setTimeOut` pero creo que con el loop el tiempo de la pista no vuelve a cero, así que estoy un poco perdido, no se como lograrlo.

```js
var beat = document.getElementById('beat');
var armony = document.getElementById('armony');
var long = 4.8;
beat.loop = true;
armony.loop = true;

function playBeat() {  
    if (beat.paused) {
        if (armony.paused){
            beat.play();
            beat.currentTime = 0;
        }
        else {
            var current = armony.currentTime,
                tiempo = (long - current) - 0.2;
            setTimeout(playBeat, tiempo);
        }
    }
    else {
        beat.pause();
        beat.currentTime = 0;
    }
}

function playArmony() {  
    if (armony.paused) {
        if (beat.paused) {
            armony.play();
            armony.currentTime = 0;
        }
        else {
            var current = beat.currentTime,
                tiempo = (long - current) - 0.2;
            setTimeout(playArmony, tiempo);
        }
    }
    else {
        armony.pause();
        armony.currentTime = 0;
    }
}

function main (){
    playBeat();
    playArmony();
}
```

```html
<div class="pad" id="padDrum" onclick="playBeat()">D</div>
    <div class="pad" id="padArmony" onclick="playArmony()">A</div>
    
    <audio id="beat">
        <source src="music/beat.wav" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
    <audio id="armony">
        <source src="music/armonico.wav" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
```

Comment: Si pero no tiene nada que ver. Ese enlace simplemente quiere sincronizar, yo intento que una vez lanzado un audio, si otro se activa se lance cuando el otro termine y comience a sonar de nuevo (loop)

Comment: Ok, gracias por la aclaración. Voy a quitar mi voto de cierre y votar por reabrir.